Buffer around line geometry
I am working on a distance analysis. I have a road layout that consists of all the major roads and the train lines etc. I dissolved and merged them. And I also used "fix geometries" after. When i finally would like to create "buffer" on this layer, neither of the tools are working for me.
I used "v.buffer" from GRASS, the most common one "buffer" tool from vector geometry, "tapped geometry" which apparently is for lines only.
They all get stuck at 25% or 40%, or it stops responding, even if I wait for hours no result.
Here is how it looks, I know it is the regional layout so there might be too may lines but I have dissolved them already. Road layout
If you'd like to download the shapefile I uploaded it here in a google drive folder The shape file drive link
Eventually, I need to do buffer for 0.5km, 1km, 5km, 10km, 10+ km. So I have to do this process 5 times, it should be an easy one so that I can repeat.
If you also know a better way for creating buffers for certain distances such the interval between 0.5-1 or 1-5 or 5-10 etc that would be great because I am planning on having those intervals manually by extracting each previous one from the next one but this is another topic. If I could just find a way to complete the buffers that would solve the majority of my problem.


First of all, the provided layer is not a "shapefile", but it's a GeoPackage layer.
In order to create a buffer around the features' geometries stored in the provided layer in a reasonable time using QGIS, ensuring your system has enough RAM available, you need to:

use the processing algorithm "Vector geometry" -> "Multipart to singleparts" to create a single-parts layer from the provided layer

then, either:

use the processing algorithm "Vector geometry" -> "Buffer" to create the desired buffer setting the single-parts layer as the algorithm's input and setting the "Dissolve result" option if you want the resulting buffer dissolved and setting the "Keep disjoint results separate" option if you want to dissolve only the connected buffers

or:

use the processing algorithm "Vector geometry" -> "Buffer" to create the desired buffer using the single-parts layer as input
use the processing algorithm "Vector geometry" -> "Dissolve" setting the previous buffered layer as the algorithm's input if you want the resulting buffer dissolved and the "Keep disjoint results separate" if you want to dissolve only the connected buffers


Hello, thank you for your comment.
Yes, as I mentioned in my post, I dissolved each of the source layers before merging them, resulting in 4 features in the final merged file. This was on purpose, to understand the source layers.
I tried "Multipart to singleparts" and then "Buffer" it works! Thank you!
As a curiosity, may I ask, why did the multiple to singleparts worked actually? Because the reason I dissolved them in the first place was because buffer didn't work with 50k features in the attribute. But with dissolve, merge, then multiple to singleparts create multiple features again..

I don't know why it didn't work with the original non dissolved layer. You need to provide it in order to be inspected.
If the answer solved your issue, please remember to "accept" this answer.

In general, most geospatial operations will be more efficient on some more less complicated geometries than on a few super complex ones. For buffer, you can just loop through all geometries one by one and apply the buffer, so at one time only few points need to be in memory and taken in account. With one huge geometry all points need to be in memory and accounted for in the processing. So for any spatial processing, if you can do multi to single, always a good idea for performance.
